# C++ Data Type Range

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to do a division of :-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int A = -2147483648;
  int B = -1;
  int C = A/B;
  // this is not working
  cout<<C<<endl;
 // nor this is working
  cout<<A/B<<endl;
// But this is working
  cout<<-2147483648/-1<<endl; // printing the result 2147483648;
}
```

I am confused why this happening. Please explain.

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working". (And remember that overflowing a signed integer has undefined behaviour.)

Comment: Dont use ; `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;`
Have a look at : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits to avoid running into corner cases. Try for -2147483477. (Negative integer numbers of 1 larger range then positive ones). It is part of signed integer arithmetic, so this is not a bug

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) - *Never*, ever, include that header. And if you want people to take your question serious, then get rid of it at once, since just the fact that you have that header included clearly shows that you have *no idea what you are doing*.

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: none of this is "working" for me: https://godbolt.org/z/8bdoEEYxe. You should include output and expected output in the question. If it is necessary to change the code to see the effect you refer to then also post that modified code please

Comment: Note that `-2147483648` is not a literal negative number, it is the negation of a literal positive number. Since `2147483648` does not fit in `int`, its type is the next wider signed integer type (probably `long long int`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `int` type is 32-bits and uses two's complement representation, the first two cases exhibit undefined behavior because both `-2147483648` and `-1` fit in a `int` but `2147483648` does not.

In the third case, the expression `-2147483648/-1` contains the [integer literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) `2147483648` (before being negated), and has the first type in which the value can fit. In this case, that would be `long int`. The rest of the calculation keeps the type, so no undefined behavior occurs.

Comment: Okay Yes i just searched the limit of int 2147483648 int can't store this number but i changed the code to :-

int A = -2147483648;
int B = -1;
long int C = A/B;
cout<<C<<endl; // this is also not working even i stored the data in long long then also?

Comment: @Gaurav The expression `A/B` still has type `int`. Try `static_cast<long>(A)/B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data type to long long.
`long long A = -2147483648;`
`long long B = -1;`
`long long C = A/B;`
If your you need fractional result, try 'double' instead of 'long long'.